# Can Document Picker be used without being the member of Apple Developer Program?

Tags: ios, uidocumentpickervc

Can we use Document Picker without being the member of Apple Developer Program? If Yes, then how?
Xcode doesn't allow to add iCloud entitlement without becoming a member. How to get around this problem. See the images below.
**Image1:** [image]

**Image2:** [image]

See this link: [developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/) It states that to use iCloud/CloudKit we need to enrol for Apple developers program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be part of Apple's dev program to utilize any of the capabilities e.g. Notifications, iCloud, Game Center etc. There's no way around this, that's the way it is.

If you want to Open/Save iOS documents without iCloud, you can just directly save to app sandbox e.g.:

```
let documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
let writePath = documents.stringByAppendingPathComponent("foo.bar")
```

Then use writeToFile for the corresponding type.

If you're on OS X then you can use NSOpenPanel, NSSavePanel instead, these let you access the local file system and do not require Apple dev provision.

(edited to differentiate between iOS and OS X solutions)